# How to display each object's attribute in a different line for readability in the Command Line using Ruby language?

Tags: ruby, linux, command-line, terminal

Is there a method or command that I could call to make an object more readable in the command line? 
Something where I could display this:

```
[6] pry(main)> job.subscription
=> #<Subscription id: 21, frequency: 0, user_id: 88, created_at: "2016-02-24 09:34:46", updated_at: "2016-02-24 09:34:47", customer_note_security: "I generally just leave the door wide open", customer_note_cleaning: "Please clean the cat too", merchant_id: nil, deleted_at: nil, repeat_reminder_sent_at: nil, store_id: nil, next_job_date: nil, subscription_application_id: nil, hourly_price: nil>
```

like this

```
[6] pry(main)> job.subscription
=> #<Subscription id: 21,
frequency: 0, 
user_id: 88,
created_at: "2016-02-24 09:34:46", 
updated_at: "2016-02-24 09:34:47", 
customer_note_security: "I generally just leave the door wide open", 
customer_note_cleaning: "Please clean the cat too", 
merchant_id: nil, 
deleted_at: nil, 
repeat_reminder_sent_at: nil, 
store_id: nil, 
next_job_date: nil,
subscription_application_id: nil,
hourly_price: nil>
```

Using pp

```
[36] pry(main)> pp job
#<Job id: 23, subtotal: #<BigDecimal:7fbf644986c8,'0.0',9(18)>, hours: #<BigDecimal:7fbf644989c0,'0.0',9(18)>, subscription_id: 22, address_id: 37, state: "unpaid", date: "2016-02-27", time_preferences: "MyString", type: nil, region: "auckland", items: [], options: {}, created_at: "2016-02-24 09:59:52", updated_at: "2016-02-24 09:59:52", merchant_id: nil, notes: nil, deleted_at: nil, merchant_rate: nil, canceled: false, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, grand_total: #<BigDecimal:7fbf64498538,'0.0',9(18)>, redemption_code_id: nil, discount_total: #<BigDecimal:7fbf64498010,'0.0',9(27)>, payment_notification_sent_at: nil, last_payment_attempt_at: nil, store_id: nil, merchant_received_notification_at: nil, customer_balance: #<BigDecimal:7fbf5af0b3a8,'0.0',9(18)>, promotional_credit_applied: #<BigDecimal:7fbf64438278,'0.0',9(18)>, spawned_by_cron: false, initial_assignment_notification_received_at: nil>
=> #<Job id: 23, subtotal: #<BigDecimal:7fbf644986c8,'0.0',9(18)>, hours: #<BigDecimal:7fbf644989c0,'0.0',9(18)>, subscription_id: 22, address_id: 37, state: "unpaid", date: "2016-02-27", time_preferences: "MyString", type: nil, region: "auckland", items: [], options: {}, created_at: "2016-02-24 09:59:52", updated_at: "2016-02-24 09:59:52", merchant_id: nil, notes: nil, deleted_at: nil, merchant_rate: nil, canceled: false, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, grand_total: #<BigDecimal:7fbf64498538,'0.0',9(18)>, redemption_code_id: nil, discount_total: #<BigDecimal:7fbf64498010,'0.0',9(27)>, payment_notification_sent_at: nil, last_payment_attempt_at: nil, store_id: nil, merchant_received_notification_at: nil, customer_balance: #<BigDecimal:7fbf5af0b3a8,'0.0',9(18)>, promotional_credit_applied: #<BigDecimal:7fbf64438278,'0.0',9(18)>, spawned_by_cron: false, initial_assignment_notification_received_at: nil>
[37] pry(main)>
```

Comment: I use gem pry-rails and the results just as you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: @vinibol12 did you try my solution?"

Comment: @abookyun I haven't yet. I am working on a project and I didn't want to install a gem only for this. Say I don't want to keep afterwards can I remove the gem and leave no trace of it if I do it before committing? 
It's my first job and I don't want to mess up with the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PrettyPrint](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) standard library included in Ruby.

```
require 'pp'

h = {mula: 'khao', alu: 'khamu na', lorem: 'You can use the PrettyPrint standard library included in Ruby.'}

pp h
#=> {:mula=>"khao",
# :alu=>"khamu na",
# :lorem=>"You can use the PrettyPrint standard library included in Ruby."}
```

Or if you want more control, like color, indent etc, you can try [awesome print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) gem.

Update, with `Struct`:

```
[1] pry(main)> Customer = Struct.new(:mula, :alu, :lorem)
=> Customer
[2] pry(main)> a = Customer.new('khao', 'khamu na', 'You can use the PrettyPrint standard library included in Ruby.')
=> #<struct Customer mula="khao", alu="khamu na", lorem="You can use the PrettyPrint standard library included in Ruby.">
[3] pry(main)> pp a
#<struct Customer
 mula="khao",
 alu="khamu na",
 lorem="You can use the PrettyPrint standard library included in Ruby.">
=> #<struct Customer mula="khao", alu="khamu na", lorem="You can use the PrettyPrint standard library included in Ruby.">
[4] pry(main)>
```

Comment: should it run fine from the Rails console? It still returns the object all on the same line. See added code in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Rails pretty print object [`attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes%3D):

```
pp job.subscription.attributes
```

or similarly:

```
pp job.attributes
```

otherwise you can convert the object to Hash and pretty print it using `pp`.